# Unable to Find Laravel Image Optimizer Package any suggestions?

Tags: php, image, laravel, optimization

I have tried hard on finding the Image Optimization plugin the optimizes the image(not resizing) but couldn't find any. I even tried Packagist their where a lot of packages but none of them worked for me.. Has any one had experience on it any help would be much appriciated.

Comment: best list ones you have tried and are no good, else you'll get loads of response(s) and they might have been no good already, one i used but might no be what your after etc i http://image.intervention.io/ also explain exactly more detail on optimization requirements

Comment: try this https://github.com/approached/laravel-image-optimizer